# How can I grant Dial-In / Network Access Permission to local account via command line?

Tags: windows, vpn, powershell, remote-access, user-management

I am trying to configure a VPN server completely using Powershell. I have completed everything except the last step: Granting a local user account Dial-In / Network Access Permissions so that this user can access the VPN.

Via GUI it's easy to complete this step with the "Computer Management" app in the user properties / Dial In / Network Access Permission:

[image]

But how can I do this via Powershell? As an alternative, how can I grant the user permission to use the VPN by setting a NPS Network Policy via command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

netsh seems to be able to do that.

```
netsh ras set user <username> permit
```

Comment: It does, indeed. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is it possible to do this for a group?

Comment: do you know which command to assign a static ipv4 address in the dial-in?